# Can the AWS Credentials from Cognito send request to other Regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-regions, aws-credentials

I created a user pool and an identity pool in one region.

Can I use the credentials from the identity pool (accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, securityToken) to access data in another region?

Answer (score 2):

All IAM credentials are global credentials, so by default this would work.

You can limit this by applying policies with the `aws:RequestedRegion` condition - more on that [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-requestedregion).

These policies can be either applied to the role Cognito creates credentials for or via a Service Control Policy, that limits which regions the account has access to.